# Button's :active state doesn't return to :hover state after releasing mouse button in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

This problem only occurs to me in Safari, and it does not show in a fiddle or a snippet. You'll have to save it to a local file and open it. Here's my code:

```
<head>
    <style>
        .testclass {
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #f00;
            width: 100px;
            border: none;
        }

        .testclass:hover {
            background-color: #0f0;
        }

        .testclass:active {
            background-color: #00f;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="testdiv" class="testclass">
      Test
    </button>
</body>
```

After clicking, the button remains blue until you move the cursor - unlike the expected green state.

**UPDATE:** I'm using 10.13 High Sierra and Safari 11.0. Upon further testing, the latest version of Safari Technology Preview still haven't fixed this bug. However, both latest Chrome and Firefox on my Mac appears to be just fine. My friend's Mac on 10.12 and Safari 10 doesn't have this problem either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I've realized this is a fairly new bug, and it's still being worked on.

Page on webkit bugzilla: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=174562

Hopefully they will resolve the issue soon.